# $A \in M_n(\mathbb F)$, sum in all rows and column transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, solution-verification

Let $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ such that:

$(a)$ sum of elements in each row equals $0$. Prove $\det A=0$

$(b)$ sum of elements in each row equals $1$. Prove $\det (A-I)=0$

$(c)$ what if the sum of elements in each row equals $5$?

Element $a_{ij}$ in $\text{the j-th column}$ can be written as a linear combination of the rest of the elements in the $i-th\;\text{row}$ depending on 
the condition in the subtasks.

$(a)$
$$a_{ik}=-\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne k}^{n} a_{ij}\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$$
Therefore we can add all of the columns to the $\text{k-th column}$ to get a zero-column$$a_{ik}=-\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^{n} a_{ij}+\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^{n} a_{ij}=0\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$$
$$\implies r(A)<n\implies \det(A)=0.$$

$(b)$
$$a_{ii}=1-\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^{n} a_{ij}\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$$
Element $\displaystyle(A-I)_{ii}=1-\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^{n} a_{ij}-1=-\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^{n}a_{ij}\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$

Therefore we can add all of the columns to an arbitrary one to get a zero-column again.$$a_{ik}=-\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^{n} a_{ij}+\sum_{j=1,\\j\ne i}^{n} a_{ij}=0\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$$
$$\implies r(A)<n\implies \det(A)=0.$$
$(c)$ My conclusion in general: if the sum of elements in each column equals $n$ $$\det(A-n\cdot I)=0$$
And so it would be for $n=5$:
$$\det(A-5\cdot I)=0$$
Is this correct?

Comment: This looks correct! Note another way of checking part (a): if $v$ denotes a column vector of all $1$s, then the assumption implies $Av$ is the zero vector, which reveals that $A$ is not invertible. Similar considerations show that $v$ is an eigenvector for $A$ in all three parts of the question.