# Proof verification for determining the determinant of A where the sum of every row of A is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Could you please review my proof?

Let $ (F, +, \cdot) $ be a field and $A$ be a a matrix of order $n$ over $F$. Assume that for each $1\le i\le n,\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}=0$. I want to prove that $\det(A)=0$.

Take $s\in F$ such that $s\neq 0$ (For example $ 1 $ ). Let $0\le i \le n$. We shall look at the $i_{\text{th}}$ row.

$sa_{i,1}+\ldots+sa_{i,n}=s(a_{i, 1}+\ldots+a_{i,n})=s(0)=0$.

Therefore, the vector $ (s,\ldots, s) \in F^n $ is a non-trivial solution to the homogenous system $ Ax=0$, which means the rows of $ A $ are linearly dependent $\Rightarrow A$ is singular $\Rightarrow\det(A)=0$.

Comment: Yes, this looks good.

Comment: You may also see this under [$(a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482178/721644).